# How to check FlatList if its null or not

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

How can I check the FlatList if it's null or not and if null I will display something like `No Available Booking's`? I have tried the code below using short hand operator but it's not working.

```
{bookings == null ?
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>No Availabe Booking's Yet!</Text>
    </View>
    :
    <FlatList
        data={bookings}
        renderItem={flatListItem}
        refreshing={refresh}
        onRefresh={refreshSummary}
        keyExtractor={item => item._id}
    />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making checks on the data and conditionally rendering the `FlatList` and the empty list view, you can use the existing `prop` provided by the `FlatList` i.e. `ListEmptyComponent`. You can read more about the `FlatList` and its other props in the official documentation of the React-Native [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#listemptycomponent).

A typical usage of the `ListEmptyComponent` could be:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';

export default class BookingsList extends PureComponent {
    state = {
        bookings: [
            // {
            //     _id: 1,
            //     title: 'I am a booking'
            // }
        ],
        refreshing: false
    };

    keyExtractor = (item) => String(item._id);
    refreshSummary = () => {};

    renderBookings = ({ item }) => (
        <View style={styles.bookingCard}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
        </View>
    );

    renderItemSeparatorComponent = () => <View style={styles.separator} />;

    //render the empty list component in case the data array for the FlatList is empty
    renderListEmptyComponent = () => (
        <View style={styles.emptyListContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.noBookingsFound}>
                No Availabe Booking's Yet!
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
    render() {
        const { bookings, refreshing } = this.state;

        return (
            <FlatList
                data={bookings}
                refreshing={refreshing}
                renderItem={this.renderBookings}
                onRefresh={this.refreshSummary}
                ListEmptyComponent={this.renderListEmptyComponent} //<==== here
                ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderItemSeparatorComponent}
                contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
                keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
            />
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    bookingCard: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        padding: 10,
        marginTop: 2,
        borderBottomWidth: 0.5
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
    emptyListContainer: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    noBookingsFound: {
        fontSize: 16,
    },
    separator: {
        height: 15
    },
    list: {
        paddingHorizontal: 15,
        paddingBottom: 40
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Would booking not be an Array for a flatlist ?

```
return (
{bookings !== undefined && bookings.length > 0 ?
    <View>
    <FlatList
        data={bookings}
        renderItem={flatListItem}
        refreshing={refresh}
        onRefresh={refreshSummary}
        keyExtractor={item => item._id}
    />
    </View>
   :
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>No Availabe Booking's Yet!</Text>
    </View>
  }
);
```

** Edited as I think I missed your point!

You can return a conditional view in React Native as follows

```
return (
  <View>
    {state.someVar == null ?
       (<ACOMPONENT />)
    :
      (<ADIFFCOMPONENT />)
    }
  </View>
);
```

Hopefully that's a better response.

Answer (score 0):

u can use `listemptycomponent`

> Rendered when the list is empty. Can be a React Component Class, a render function, or a rendered element.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#listemptycomponent

```
    <FlatList
        data={bookings}
        renderItem={flatListItem}
        refreshing={refresh}
        onRefresh={refreshSummary}
        keyExtractor={item => item._id}
        ListEmptyComponent={<View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>No Availabe Booking's Yet!</Text>
    </View>}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
{ bookings && Array.isArray(bookings) ? (
    <FlatList
        data={bookings}
        renderItem={flatListItem}
        refreshing={refresh}
        onRefresh={refreshSummary}
        keyExtractor={item => item._id}
    />
   ) : (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>No Availabe Booking's Yet!</Text>
        </View>
     )
}
```